# Elastic search Nest Client is very slow

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, nest

Testing Environment Laptop is 4 core CPU, 16GB RAM and 512GB SSD.

Elasticsearch is running single node on windows server 2012 VM. This VM has 16GB RAM and 4 core CPU.

The Elasticsearch have 18 GB data. I am using NEST version: 7.6.1 for indexing and query
Same query with Postman is taking only 1221 ms but with NEST client it is taking about 10-13 seconds for 10000 size.
When I decrease the page size query time is decreased for 3000 it is taking almost 5 seconds.

Benchmarks of same query for REST Client and NEST Client.
Nest client took: 12384 ms
Nest client documents: 10000
Rest client took: 1966 ms

I have build Elasticsearch repository in asp.net core 3.1.

Settings of Client

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri(url))
.EnableDebugMode()

    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(client);`
```

Get List Method

```
public List GetList(SearchDescriptor descriptor, string index = null) where T : class, IElasticBaseModel
{
descriptor.From(0)
.Take(scrollPageSize).Scroll("5m");

    index = index ?? _options.DefaultIndex;
    descriptor = descriptor.Index(index);
    var searchResponse = _client.Search<T>(descriptor);
    var results = new List<T>();

    while (true)
    {
        if (!searchResponse.IsValid || string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchResponse.ScrollId))
            throw new Exception($"Search error: {searchResponse.ServerError.Error.Reason}");

        if (!searchResponse.Documents.Any())
            break;

        results.AddRange(searchResponse.Documents);
        searchResponse = _client.Scroll<T>("5m", searchResponse.ScrollId);
    }

    _client.ClearScroll(new ClearScrollRequest(searchResponse.ScrollId));
    return results;
}
```

This query took 11.5 seconds.

Below is Debug Info from NEST client.

Valid NEST response built from a successful (200) low level call on POST: /position/_search?pretty=true&error_trace=true&typed_keys=true&scroll=5m

Audit trail of this API call:
[1] HealthyResponse: Node: http://myip:9200/ Took: 00:00:08.9185311
Request:

```
 {"from":0,"query":{"bool":{"filter":[{"bool":{"must":[{"geo_bounding_box":{"boost":1.1,"validation_method":"coerce","type":"indexed","location":{"bottom_right":{"lat":47.6125,"lon":39.575},"top_left":{"lat":64.8875,"lon":-17.075}}}}],"should":[{"bool":{"filter":[{"bool":{"should":[{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"machine":["6F1401","6G1519"]}},{"range":{"time":{"gte":"2019-09-01T00:00:00Z","lte":"2019-09-30T23:59:59.9999999Z"}}}]}}]}}]}}]}}]}},"size":10000}`
```

Response:

```
{
"_scroll_id" : "DXF1ZXJ5QW5kRmV0Y2gBAAAAAAAHY_0WVlFRQlpTazJSUjZKbjJ4OGplQlJ3UQ==",
"took" : 2876,
"timed_out" : false,
"_shards" : {
"total" : 1,
"successful" : 1,
"skipped" : 0,
"failed" : 0
},
"hits" : {
"total" : {
"value" : "59128374",
"relation" : "eq"
},
"max_score" : 0.0,
"hits" : [
{
"_index" : "position",
"_type" : "_doc",
"_id" : "6H1561_1541153618.03",
"_score" : 0.0,
"_source" : {
"id" : "6H1561_1541153618.03",
"time" : "2018-11-02T10:13:38.0300000Z",
"machine" : "6H1561",
"orderid" : 56,
"bunkerunloading" : false,
"operatingmode" : 1,
"depthguidanceon" : true,
"engineon" : true,
"istimelygap" : false,
"identifier" : 6852,
"location" : {
"lat" : 50.613713333,
"lon" : 4.014146667
}
}
}
```

Comment: Generally Serialization <--> Deserialization are considered as CPU hungry operations, specially if you are dealing with nested objects. It would be good if you can share some example code what you have tried and how you know it is due to serialization?

Comment: @MuhammadUmmar I have updated the Question. Please let me know if you need more info